# How to keep integrity of data intact from View, to Controller, to a Service

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am working on a project using an Entity Framework Code-First approach. We have a context class, service, repository and interface layers. We would like to be able to keep validation and any sort of object mapping in the service class for the specific entity. However, we don't really like messing with Lists of Key Value Pairs, and we feel passing the entire form collection to the service would be burdensome. And, using passing a Model back from the View would result in string entries converting to 0 for numeric properties... halting any proper validation. We know there is the Entity Validation that would prevent a form from even being submitted, but we would like a layer of "security" if you will by using validation in the back-end.

Our google-fu is reaching an end! Our powers useless.

We would like to know if there is any nice and clean way of passing a data from a Form collection from the controller to a Service method without using a List of Key Value Pairs, passing the collection itself, or mapping a Model?

Comment: Describe what you mean by `passing a Model back from the View would result in string entries converting to 0 for numeric properties`. With MVC, all of the data type conversion from the form post is done automatically by the framework. The model object you receive as a parameter in the action method is a good model.

Comment: @JoeEnos You are correct - it would be a good model. However, we would like to use our own validation that we write in the service layers. Let us say we have a model, with an ID property of a long data type. If the user types in a string and submits the form, we would like to be able to pass the entirety of the form collection into the service layers to validate it. However, if we simply pass the model back, with a string inputted into the ID field, MVC would convert it to a 0. Alas, not allowing us to validate and display errors. Sorry, hope I am explaining it in well enough detail!

Comment: @JoeEnos I should add: and the string the user enters is not convertible to a long.

Comment: Gotcha, makes sense. Added an answer with my recommendation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to keep type-safe models on the MVC side, which I think is the right thing to do, I think your best bet is to do some initial validation in the MVC world before sending your data off to your service. You can see if your model is valid, and get all basic errors with something like:

```
var errors = ModelState.Values.SelectMany(v => v.Errors);
```

If this collection has any items, then it will contain errors showing where the model mapping went wrong. If your client validation is working, then this should never happen, but you've still got it here in case they disable client validation. If you can't generate a valid model out of the post, then it's a waste to even send it to the web service, so don't even bother. It means that the user screwed up big and doesn't deserve a full post validation. So stop them there.

If the model is valid (no errors in that collection, or `ModelState.IsValid`), then you know that at least the post had the appropriate data types, and you can send your model off to your service for the real business validation, knowing that the values were all posted properly.